# I'm stuck in easy query

Tags: mysql, sql

That's my table:

[image]

I have to count how many distinct ID_Utente are followed by every ID_Ist.
I've tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(ID_Utente),ID_Ist
FROM scheda
GROUP BY ID_Ist
```

but it shows the count of every occurrence of ID_Utente where ID_Ist appears,so it doesn't show what I want.
This should be stupidly easy to do but I'm stuck and I don't know what to do since I've also tried multiple different queries but nothing

Answer (score 1):

You want `count(distinct)`, not `distinct count()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID_Utente), ID_Ist
FROM scheda
GROUP BY ID_Ist;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ID_Utente) as idcount ,ID_Ist FROM scheda GROUP BY ID_Ist
```